# remove special characters in a xml file using sed command

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace special character (.) from an XML file using:

```
 find . -type f -name "*.XML" -exec sed -e 's/\.//g' {} +
```

My file content is as below and the string value is dynamic or repetitive. It has to specifically search for this and replace the contents ignoring the special characters.

Example 1:

```
<TotalSum>1000.01</TotalSum><Info><Value>DDAB.A1234 1000.01</Value></Info>
```

Output should be as

```
<TotalSum>1000.01</TotalSum><Info><Value>DDABA1234 1000 01</Value></Info>
```

Example 2:

```
<TotalSum>300.89</TotalSum><Info><Value>A.1234567 100.14 B.1234567 200.75</Value></Info>
```

Output should be as

```
<TotalSum>300.89</TotalSum><Info><Value>A1234567 100 14 B1234567 200 75</Value></Info>
```

The script I was trying to execute was as below as I only need to remove special chars from `<Value>` field:

```
$search_text=`grep -i Value filename`
for i in $search_text
 do
    sed -e 's/\.//g'
 done
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I used below command but it is failing
       sed 's/\<Value>\.//g' file.txt

Comment: Always include the code you've tried in the question, not in the comments. The point of doing that is to show some effort :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments PesaThe. The command you gave me was replacing all over the file. I've rephrased my question with my attempts.

Comment: To mention the values should be changed only in `<Value>` is a very crucial information :) Updated my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) with extended regex:

```
sed -r '
    :del 
    s#(<Value>.*[[:digit:]])\.(.*</Value>)#\1 \2# 
    s#(<Value>.*[[:alpha:]])\.(.*</Value>)#\1\2#
    tdel
' file
```

or as a one-liner:

```
sed -r ':del; s#(<Value>.*[[:digit:]])\.(.*</Value>)#\1 \2#; s#(<Value>.*[[:alpha:]])\.(.*</Value>)#\1\2#; t del' file
```

- `-r` for extended regex. It's just for convenience, otherwise you would have to use `\( ... \)`
- `s#text#replacement#` you can choose a different delimiter also just for convenience. Then there is no need to escape literal `/`
- `:del` is a definiton of a label
- `( )` save the matches that can be later [back-referenced](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions) using `\1`, `\2`, ...
- `tdel` jumps to label `:del` if the `s` commands changed the line. This is to ensure all of the dots get replaced

---

This `sed` will not work for multiple `<Value>` tags on the same line as basic and extended regular expressions don't support non-greedy matching. I suggest using `perl` or some XML-aware tool.

Comment: Its kinda working but the issue is it is looking for first instance of <Value> and starting from there it is replacing it everywhere.

Comment: @Prasad what do you mean? It replaces `.` when it is inside `<Value>`. You want it only in the first `<Value>` tag on the line? Show some input that demonstrates it...I cannot guess what you want if you don't describe it properly.

Comment: what it is doing right now is that it is looking at <Value> for the first instance and from there replacing everywhere:
    <Curr>='USD'<Amnt>=12345.45</Amnt></Curr>
    <TotalSum>1000.01</TotalSum><Info><Value>DDABA1234 1000 01</Value></Info>
     <TotalSum>300 89</TotalSum><Info><Value>A1234567 100 14 B1234567 200 75</Value></Info>
    <TotalSum>3500 89</TotalSum><Info><Value>TEST4590 1000 85 EA1111 2500 04</Value></Info>

Comment: @Prasad I see what you mean now. For that I would suggest using `perl` as basic/extended regex doesn't support non-greedy expressions. Or use some XML-aware tool :)